# Nested urls are not working with Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

```
url.py
router.register(r'Costumers', CostumerViewSet, base_name='costumer')
  .register(r'Agreements', AgreementViewSet, base_name='agreement', parents_query_lookups=['costumer']).
      .register(r'Programs', ProgramViewSet,base_name='programs',parents_query_lookups=['agreement']),

model.py

class Costumer(models.Model):
  company_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
  supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier)

class Agreement(models.Model): 
  agreement_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
  programs = models.ManyToManyField(Program, through='Programs_in_Agreement')
  costumer = models.ForeignKey(Costumer)

class Program(models.Model):
  program_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Programs_in_Agreement(models.Model):
   programs = models.ForeignKey(Program)
   agreement = models.ForeignKey(Agreement)

Im trying to get this page 
/api/v1/Costumers/1/Agreements/1/Programs/

and I've got this error
"^Costumers/(?P<parent_lookup_agreement>[^/.]+)/Agreements/(?P<parent_lookup_agreement>[^/.]+)/Programs/$" is not a valid regular expression: redefinition of group name 'parent_lookup_agreement' as group 2; was group 1
```

the relation between Programs and Agreements is M2M
and the relation between Agreement and costumer is M21
can somone help me please?

Answer (score 4):

You are nesting the routers, which means you are using one of the nested router plugins. The problem is that you are not providing all of the lookup fields for the last `register` call.

The relationship that it looks like you are trying to achieve is

> Program -> Agreement -> Costumers

And the routers are generating

> Costumers
>   Agreement -> Costumers
>   Program -> Agreement -> Costumers

Where the `->` signals the lookup that is being made. **The lookup must manually be provided** when registering by passing in `parents_query_lookups`. This is important, as otherwise the plugin has to guess what the lookup is, and it's bound to be wrong. The lookups are not maintained across nestings of the routers, so a lookup defined on router A will not be passed down to router B, it **must be repeated** on router B as well.

So what you should be doing when registering the router is passing in the parent lookup. The snippet below should work:

```
router.register(r'Costumers', CostumerViewSet, base_name='costumer')
  .register(r'Agreements', AgreementViewSet, base_name='agreement', parents_query_lookups=['costumer']).
      .register(r'Programs', ProgramViewSet, base_name='programs', parents_query_lookups=['agreement__costumer', 'agreement'])
```

Note the addition of `agreement__costumer` in the `parents_query_lookups` for the last call. This allows the plugin to fill in the lookup field for that part of the URL, preventing duplicated groups from showing up.